# How to split a dynamic string in rows (right to Left)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query converts dynamic int to binary, but I want to split into rows.

```
declare @value int 
set @value = 96

declare @result varchar(32) 
set @result = '' 

while 1 = 1 
begin
    select 
        @result = convert(char(1), @value % 2) + ',' +@result,
        @value = convert(int, @value / 2) 

    if @value = 0 break  
end

select substring(@result, 1, len(@result)-1) as result
```

Please help me to find a solution.

This is the result of my query.

```
1,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

My question is: how can I split this result into rows from right to left?

My result will need to be this (I'm trying to insert into a #table):

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Ohh sorry sqlserver 2008 or 2012 please! thanks

Comment: There's a big difference between the 2, and one is about to run out of support. 2008 or 2012?

Comment: Ok, can you help me to find a solution in 2008 please? if is possible one example using 2012. If is possible!. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `WHILE` seems like a really bad idea. If you want to achieve what you have this would be a far faster solution:

```
DECLARE @I int = 96

SELECT CONVERT(bit,@i & V.b)
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(4),(8),(16),(32),(64)) V(b)
ORDER BY V.b;
```